Fail to replicate literature in 1935: Schrödinger equation for a double-well system results in noisy eigenfunctions
I'm trying to get numerical solutions to a double-well potential in regards to the inversion of an ammonia molecule. This has been done before, and I'm trying to replicate literature results in 1935 with Mathematica's modern methods. According to the literature, the Manning-Rosen potential for ammonia is:
$$V(x)=66551\text{ cm}^{-1}\times{}\text{sech(}\frac{x}{2\rho})^4-105619\text{ cm}^{-1}\times{}\text{sech(}\frac{x}{2\rho})^2$$
where,
$$\rho = \frac{6.97\times10^{-11}\text{ m amu}^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\sqrt{\mu}}.$$
Here, $\mu$ is the reduced mass of the inversion coordinate in atomic mass units, described by,
$$\mu=\frac{3M_HM_N}{3M_H+M_N}.$$
This is a classic double-well potential that relates the coordinate $x$, which refers to the distance from nitrogen atom the the plane of the hydrogen atoms, which are held in a rigid triangle, to the potential $V(x)$ in wavenumbers. (Not the best approximation but it does the job for 1935, and Manning did get reasonable results with it.)
The first two Eigenstates of this system are the symmetric and antisymmetric states, which are separated by the splitting, or tunneling energy. Experimentally, this energy is around $0.79\text{ cm}^{-1}$. Manning was able to get $0.83\text{ cm}^{-1}$.
Below is my code for trying to numerically solve this problem to get a good approximation of the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of the system, but I run into a big problem, where the wavefunctions look like complete garbage compared to the potential, and the eigenvalues in turn make no sense either. Any ideas where I've gone wrong? I've also attached photos of what the results of the plots are.
h = Quantity[6.626*10^-34, "Joules"*"Seconds"];
ℏ = h/(2 π);
c = Quantity[2.9979*10^8, ("Meters")/("Seconds")]; (* Speed of light in m/s*)
Voffset = 
  Quantity[-8.966556*10^-19, 
   "Joules"]; (* Vertical offset for the manning potential so that \
the minima are on the x-axis *)
MH = Quantity[1.00784, "AtomicMassUnit"]; (* Mass of Hydrogen in amu *)
MN = Quantity[14.0067, "AtomicMassUnit"]; (* Mass of Nitrogen in amu*)
μ = (3 MH MN)/(
  3 MH + MN); (*Reduced mass in amu, this should be converted within \
the NDEigensystem function to kilograms as per the documentation so \
no need to change it*)
ρ = Quantity[6.97*10^-11, Sqrt["AtomicMassUnit"]]/
  Sqrt[μ]; (* Rho parameter, techincally in units of meter, but \
since x is not in meters let's not worry about it *)
V[x_] := (h c (Quantity[
      66551 Sech[x/(2 ρ)]^4 - 109619 Sech[x/(2 ρ)]^2, 
      "Wavenumbers"]) - 
   Voffset) (* Manning potential from the original 1935 paper, but \
converted into joules *)
bound = 1*10^-10; (* Bounds for computation and plotting *)
ℋ = 
  SchrodingerPDEComponent[{Ψ[x], {x}}, <|"Mass" -> μ, 
    "SchrodingerPotential" -> V[x], 
    "ReducedPlancksConstant" -> ℏ|>]; (* Setting up the \
equation with the parameters *)
{vals, funs} = 
 NDEigensystem[ℋ, Ψ[x], {x, -bound, bound}, 2, 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" \
-> {MaxCellMeasure -> bound/100}}}}] (* Solving it *)
Plot[{V[x], Evaluate[funs + vals]}, {x, -bound, bound}] (*Plotting*)
Plot[V[x], {x, -bound, bound}]




You're going to have a much easier time getting reliable numerical answers if you can get rid of the very large / very small numbers in the SE.  The fact that you need to focus on eg. 10^-10 is likely the cause of numerical instability.  Can you rescale to get dimensionless quantities, solve, and then restore the units?

I agree, try using atomic units

The previous comments are important!  You should always scale your variable by relevant scales for the problem instead of using just, for instance, SI units, which are generally relevant for every-day and not molecular scales. Atomic units are a good way to go here. It's a good idea to then non-dimensionalize your equations in terms of these scaling quantities before numerically solving them. Then, you, don't need to carry around all those `Qauntity's, which could slow things down. When doing numerics, only plug numbers into the computer!

Hello, welcome to MMA.SE. Then 1. @evanb and chuy and march Hmm… I doubt if rescaling is a good idea. See discussion in e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138634/1871 2. "I'm trying to replicate literature result", can you add the reference? 3. Have you checked if the equation itself (including those parameters) is correct? According to my personal experience, it's a big source of mistake. 4. Setting "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", "Shift" -> 0} results in a seemingly reasonable result, is it what you want? (Might be related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/186224/1871)

@xzczd Thank you so much! "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", "Shift" -> 0} definitely did the trick. The eigenfunctions and eigenvalues are exactly what I was looking for, and I didn't even have to change the scaling. I got 0.74 wavenumbers compared to 0.83 from the paper I'm looking at, which is in good agreement with experimental results (0.79 wavenumbers). Changing to atomic units did not help at all, was still getting bogus results until I added the aforementioned argument to the NDEigensolve function. Thank you so much!!

The reasons to move to dimensionless variables are manifold.  One is a sanity check.  Another is to avoid plugging in numbers too soon.  A third is that it can let you find dimensional errors; in executing the procedure below I found that you missed a "Meters" in your definition of rho.
Your potential is
V[x]=a Sech[x/(2ρ)]^4+b Sech[x/(2ρ)]^2+offset

and the SE has a left-hand side, kinetic, and potential contributions
LHS = Energy  ψ[x/ρ]
Potential = V[x] ψ[x/ρ]
Kinetic = -(hbar^2/(2 μ)) D[ψ[x/ρ], {x, 2}]

Notice that I have already made the argument of the wavefunction dimensionless.
Let's treat the terms of the SE separately
SE={LHS,Kinetic, Potential}

We can move to the dimensionless variable ξ = x/ρ.
SE=(SE/.x->ξ ρ)

and then we can multiply the whole equation to make the kinetic piece simple
SE=ExpandAll[(μ ρ^2)/hbar^2 SE]

Finally, let's change to dimensionless quantities
SE=(SE/.{
    Energy->(\[ScriptCapitalE] hbar^2)/(μ ρ^2),
    a->(\[ScriptCapitalA] hbar^2)/(μ ρ^2),
    b->(\[ScriptCapitalB] hbar^2)/(μ ρ^2),
    offset->\[ScriptCapitalV]0 hbar^2/(μ ρ^2)
})

We have massaged the SE to be
{
  \[ScriptCapitalE] ψ[ξ],
  -(1/2) (ψ'')[ξ],
  \[ScriptCapitalV]0 ψ[ξ]+ \[ScriptCapitalB] Sech[ξ/2]^2 ψ[ξ]+\[ScriptCapitalA] Sech[ξ/2]^4 ψ[ξ],
}

and we can recover the dimensionful energy, a, and b by inverting the above relations.
Now we can use the physical constants
(* These have exact definitions, may as well use them: *)
ℏ=Quantity["ReducedPlanckConstant"];
c=Quantity["SpeedOfLight"];
(* Slightly less precision than your manual input: *)
MH=ElementData["H","AtomicMass"]
MN=ElementData["N","AtomicMass"]

μ=(3 MH MN)/(3 MH+MN); 
ρ=Quantity[6.97*10^-11,"Meters" (*<-- this was missing before! *)
                            *Sqrt["AtomicMassUnit"]]/Sqrt[μ]; 

As well as your quoted values
a = 66551/Quantity[1, "cm"] ℏ c (* to make units of energy *)
b = -(105619/Quantity[1, "cm"]) ℏ c
offset = Quantity[8.966556*10^-19, "Joules"]

If we
UnitConvert[(a μ ρ^2)/ℏ^2]

(or likewise for b) we are supposed to get a dimensionless number, which is how I found that your definition of ρ was missing the meters.  Let's put the dimensionless numbers in
ammonia=(SE/.{
    \[ScriptCapitalA]->UnitConvert[(a μ ρ^2)/ℏ^2],
    \[ScriptCapitalB]->UnitConvert[(b μ ρ^2)/ℏ^2],
    \[ScriptCapitalV]0->UnitConvert[(offset μ ρ^2)/ℏ^2]
})
kinetic=ammonia[[2]]
potential=ammonia[[3]]

I get numerical values of -242.215 on the Sech^2 term and +152.621 on the Sech^4 term, with an offset of 650.411.
Now we can solve
bound = 20;
rhs = kinetic + potential;
{values, functions} = NDEigensystem[
   {rhs},
   ψ[ξ], {ξ, -bound, +bound}, 5,
   Method -> {
   "PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement",
                          {"MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> bound/100}}}, 
   "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", "Shift" -> 0}}];

and plot
Show[
    Plot[ammonia[[3]]/ψ[ξ], {ξ, -bound, +bound}, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All],
    Plot[Evaluate[values + functions], {ξ, -bound, +bound}]
]


The four lowest dimensionless eigenenergies are {557.087, 557.312, 561.429, 563.364, 566.698}.  We need to convert those back into dimensionless quantities.
energies = values;
dimensionful =  UnitConvert[
    (energies  ℏ^2)/(μ ρ^2) 1/(ℏ c),
    "per centimeter"]
Differences@dimensionful

The differences are {97.7936/cm,1795.47/cm,843.427/cm,1454.24/cm}, which is about 100x greater than what you suggested.  I don't know the error.  This article uses a different double-well potential.

"you missed a "Meters" in your definition of rho." In the code comment OP writes (* Rho parameter, techincally in units of meter, but since x is not in meters let's not worry about it *), so I think it's intentional?

Then I think the units of the equation may be inconsistent.

Yeah, that was intentional, since I was treating x as in meters but didn't have the actual unit attached to it. I was having lots of issues putting values with units directly into NDEigensolve, so I just decided to make sure that the input x and the output V(x) had no dimension in the code, I just kept track of it in my head.

@evanb While the dimensionless units definitely have their use case, I found it was more cumbersome than it was worth in my situation, but that may be because I'm not as well versed in Mathematica syntax as others, and I can see some nice things in your code which probably would have made it easier had I known. Nevertheless, I was able to replicate the results fairly accurately just by adding the argument xzczd mentioned without really any modification to the code.

It's definitely better to do the dimensional manipulation with paper and pencil, rather than with Mathematica!  But I thought I'd demonstrate how to do it nevertheless.

Oh 100% I agree. And thank you for demonstrating!
